# To get the details of tag associated with object when the object is evicted in Appfabric cache

Tags: c#, caching, notifications, tags, appfabric

I am using Appfabric Cache version 1.1 in C#.net framework and currently i want to get the list of tags associated with an object when that particular object gets evicted.

After doing some research, i found out that we can use the Notifications provided by Appfabric to capture the details of the object when it gets removed from the Cache.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff424507(v=azure.10).aspx
(Referred Microsoft Windows Server AppFabric Cookbook by Hammad Rajjoub as well)

But the details obtained from the callback function does not contain the list of tags which I want to retrieve.

The main purpose to get the list of tags is to remove all the other objects associated with those tags, since the data which i am supposed to store in cache is related.

Any ideas or different approach is welcome.

Comment: Item-level callbacks are only called when AddItem, ReplaceItem, or RemoveItem are explicitly called, not when items are evicted from the cache because they have expired or because of memory pressure in the cluster. Which scenario are you trying to handle?

Comment: @stuartd, I am trying to handle the scenario when the object is evicted from the cache, when cache memory has crossed the Watermark level (low or high). So as per your comment is there any other way to know the tags associated with the object when it is evicted. Thanks

Comment: It should be possible, see my [answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20121059/43846) but there's nothing built in to do so..

Comment: @stuartd, Thank you for your help, will dig in some more on the content of the link you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

AppFabric does not provides metadata with removed items. Also as @stuartd has mentioned callbacks are not called when item is removed because of eviction.

There are caching solutions other than Appfabric that provide such fearures. Like [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) allows to register [item level event notifications](http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/docs/ncache/help-4-3/dotnet-api-reference/html/ae562b96-86ed-e73f-d7d8-b44e2ce36348.htm) along with specifying type of information required when the notification is fired. You can register event notification to get items metadata only.

NCache also allows to add key-dependencies with items to set one item dependent on any other item. So that all dependent items are removed automatically if dependee is removed for any reason. Unfortunately key-dependency feature is also not yet available in AppFabric.